# Set Mockito return to be any integer except a certain value

Tags: java, mockito

Specifically, I'm trying to return any integer not equal to 1. Currently I have:

```
Mockito.when(dsIn.getItemNumber(1, "COLUMN")).thenReturn(0.0);
```

but I want something like:

```
Mockito.when(dsIn.getItemNumber(1, "COLUMN")).thenReturn(anyInt() != 1);
```

Comment: Three questions:  1) Why not just return a value that isn't 1?  2)  What are you testing in that you need this to be *every* value except 1?  Could you write a negative test to catch the 1 scenario?  3)  Why are you mocking this?  Mocks have their place but my biggest concern with your test scenario is that this isn't one for mocking.

Comment: By "return any integer not equal to 1" you mean something like a random integer != 1?

Comment: @MatheusMohr Yes

Comment: Well then, use Math.random(), generate a random int, return it, simple as that. Fastest way is to just generate a random int, use a +2 on it (so that it's always 2 or more) and return it, but you might figure something better following that logic.

Comment: I agree with @Daniel Pryden, even though there are a few ways by which you can achieve that ramdomness, your unit tests should be more specific, even if that means adding a few more tests that look similar

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually want your test cases to be different every time you run your test. You want them to be reproducible, so that when your test fails, and then you re-run the test, you get the same failure (for the same reason) as before.

If you want to ensure that *every* `int` other than `1` is valid, you could write a `for` loop over all the values, or you could pick a few "interesting" values, like `0`, `2`, `-1`, `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, etc. Either way, you should be *explicit* about what values you're testing, rather than *implicit* ("some value that isn't this one").

Or, you can just pick a number randomly and hard-code it. It's still "random":

[image: XKCD: "RFC 1149.5 specifies 4 as the standard IEEE-vetted random number."]

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this is to get a random number with range from 2 to whatever.

It would be something like this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int  n = rand.nextInt(50) + 2;
Mockito.when(dsIn.getItemNumber(1, "COLUMN")).thenReturn(n);
```

With this you will get a random number between 2 and 50.

Comment: `rand.nextInt(50) + 2` would give you a number between 2 and 51 inclusive, right? Also, I disagree that this is the "best solution" to the problem in the question.