# Is it possible to blacklist certain return values in Mockito?

Tags: java, android, mockito, android-espresso

## Background

I am trying to test this method inside a class with Mockito:

The first case of the method is when a string equals to a constant.

The second case of the method is when a string equals to anything else **except** the constant.

This is the string version of this question about [anything except a certain integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49778335/set-mockito-return-to-be-any-integer-except-a-certain-value).

```
public class Class {
    private SomeOtherObjectWithAMethod someOtherObjectWithAMethod;

    public Class(SomeOtherObjectWithAMethod someOtherObjectWithAMethod){
        this.someOtherObjectWithAMethod = someOtherObjectWithAMethod;
    }

    public void method(){
        if(helperObject.obtainAString().equals(HelperObject.A_STRING_CONSTANT)){
            someOtherObjectWithAMethod.thisMethod("stringarg");
        }
        else{
            someOtherObjectWithAMethod.thisMethod("differentarg");
        }
    }
```

I know in Mockito you can

1. Change certain return values in mockito (but only the last one will have effect) according to [durron597](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32430753/8981474)
2. Enter `null` inside a `thenReturn()` method as a means of returning nothing.
3. Use `anyString()` to serve as a dummy string.
4. Return a boolean value.

## Partial Solution

I have already unit tested the first case `(str.equals("This string"))` as written below:

```
private Class instantiatedClass;

@Test
public void testMethod_thisString(){
    whenever(helperObject.obtainAString()).thenReturn(HelperObject.A_STRING_CONSTANT);
    instantiatedClass.method()
    verify(someOtherObjectWithAMethod).thisMethod("stringarg");
}
```

I am going to write another test case method like it.  I have commented out the part I need help with below:

```
@Test
public void testMethod_notThisString(){
    whenever(helperObject.obtainAString()).thenReturn(/* A String that is not HelperObject.A_STRING_CONSTANT */);
    instantiatedClass.method()
    verify(someOtherObjectWithAMethod).thisMethod("differentarg");
}
```

## Question

How do I test for any string **except** for a specific value (or values)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't know the way to do "any string except certain ones", this solved my issue:

```
@Test
public void testMethod_notThisString(){
    whenever(helperObject.obtainAString()).thenReturn(HelperObject.CONSTANT1, HelperObject.CONSTANT2, HelperObject.CONSTANT3);
    instantiatedClass.method()
    verify(someOtherObjectWithAMethod).thisMethod("differentarg");
}
```

This follows the logic of [Overriding Stubbing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34172381/8981474).

Answer (score 0):

You can look for `creating random strings` and use them if they are not equal to specific value(values).

Answer (score 0):

You can do `Mockito.doAnswer( answer )` to have more control over the created `String`

So something like:

```
List<String> blacklist = Arrays.asList("aaaa","bbbb");
Mockito.doAnswer((i)-> { 
    String x=RandomStringUtils.random(4);
    while(blacklist.contains(x)){
        x=RandomStringUtils.random(4);
    }
    return x;
}).when(helperObject).obtainAsString();
```